# Javascript RegEx to match words without preceding or trailing hyphens

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a RegEx for Javascript which will match the string "smith" in lines 1-4 but not in lines 5-8 below.
The numbered lines are fields in an Access database (the fields do not contain the numbers).
What I have so far is:

```
var xy = 'smith';
MyString = new RegExp('(^|\\W)' + xy + '(\\W|$)', 'i');
```

This matches the Smiths in lines 1-4, but also those in Lines 7 and 8.
How can I get the expression to also ignore the Smiths which are preceded or followed by a hyphen?

1. Smith, Jones, Wilson
2. Smith Jones Wilson
3. Jones, Smith(Jr), Wilson
4. Jones, Wilson, Smith
5. Arrowsmith, Jones
6. Wilson, Smithson
7. Jones, Smith-Treadstone, Wilson
8. Wilson, Blakely-Smith, Jones

After a week and dozens of attempts, I am asking the experts!

Comment: When I wrote the two slashes before the W, I only saw one slash in the message preview window. I had to write four backslashes to be able to see two backslashes in the preview window. I clicked on Submit without realizing that the final display would not correspond to the preview version.

Comment: I edited to question (and my answer accordingly) to reflect your actual code (with the correct amount of backslashes).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write the negative character class (`\W`) yourself and include the hyphen:

```
MyString = new RegExp('(^|[^a-z0-9_-])' + xy + '([^a-z0-9_-]|$)', 'i');
```

While `\W` matches any non-word character (everything but letters, digits and underscores), `[^a-z0-9_-]` matches any character that is neither such a word character nor a hyphen.

You could of course use `\w` within that character class:

```
MyString = new RegExp('(^|[^\\w-])' + xy + '([^\\w-]|$)', 'i');
```

Comment: thanks, m.buettner, your code works perfectly, although I am curious as to why it doesn't also need A-Z within the square brackets!  ridgerunner, I am using your suggestion, because it is shorter and sweeter, but I had to add a backslash before the second w. :-)

Comment: @user1781623, it doesn't need `A-Z` because the `i` at the end means "case-insensitive"

Comment: @ridgerunner I thought so, but I wasn't really sure why the OPs version would even work the way he described it with those 4 backslashes.

Comment: @m.buettner I am new to RegExp and was not sure whether the `i` referred to the searched strings or to the criteria or both. E.g. if I wanted to match all occurrences of "qwerty" (case-insensitive) which were preceded by an uppercase "A" or a lowercase "x", then I would be puzzled. Admittedly a far-fetched example.